# Drupal6 Views and Custom handlers

Tags: php, drupal, view

Good Morning,

I am pretty new to drupal and I am attempting to create a custom argument handler that I can use in a view, I have the basics of the handler all setup and it works fine, however, I want to add something into the handler itself so that I can manipulate the value that is passed in as an argument to the view.

Here is an example of my view handler.

```
class views_handler_argument_trustcode extends views_handler_argument_string {
 function get_value() {
  return '12345';
 }
}
```

At the moment, regardless of what argument is passed into the view, I want it to use the argument 12345 but this is not happening, once I can change the value then I can manipulate it appropriately.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,